# How to remove scrollbar on web page, while it isnt required?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, scroll

I have a popup menu and i want scrollbar to appear only when it can scroll ("when overflow").
But if i apply

```
.popup-window {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It appears like this (dont care about text):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvDq4.png)

On real page it looks worse

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, you shouldn't add ***overflow-y: scroll***, you need default property

```
.popup-window {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Scroll will appear if block overflow by y. Probably you need to add ***overflow-x: hidden;***

Comment: Don't use overflow: hidden in any normal case. It will disable the scroll ability not prevent overflowing. If it overflows, you will be unable to scroll. If you want to always hide the scrollbar but still be able to scroll with wheel or finger you need to give it a height/width of 0. If you get an x-scrollbar you have done something wrong with full responsiveness the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:auto` to make it work with `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` .

It will only add scrollbar if it is needed.

```css
.popup-window {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```css
.popup-window {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Overflow: hidden will disable the scrollbar. It will be disabled even if you need it and you'll be unable to scroll then. If he actually tired to hide the stroller always then give the scrollbar a width of 0. That way you can at least scroll with mousewheel or finger. However in his case, he want a scrollbar when needed. So he just need to set overflow to auto.